# How to change a views block ID attribute to use it as anchor

Tags: views, 8, theming, blocks

I have a views block with `id=block-views-block-services-block-1` which I used in the menu link.

The menu link is now shown as https://example.com/gb/#block-views-block-services-block-1

As you can see it's really not looking nice with long hyphend words. Is there any easy way to change it to something like this https://example.com/gb/#services

I read an answer for Drupal 7 where we need to edit `template.php` to change the ID. But in Drupal 8 it seems that `template.php` is replaced with `twig.html`. I'm not very sure as I'm new to Drupal.

Could anyone please explain few steps on how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

you should place this function in your `themes/YOURTHEME/YOURTHEME.theme` file:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  dump($variables);
}
```

and you will see the name of your block. You have to look for `block_html_id`. Based on your description the value of the `block_html_id` will be `block-views-block-services-block-1`.

Then you can simply owerdefine it this way:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['block_html_id'] == "block-views-block-services-block-1") {
    $variables['block_html_id'] = "services";
  }
}
```

Or you can create a custom module and you can put this function there too. In that case you have to replace the `YOURTHEME` to the name of the custom module.

Comment: I cannot get this to work in Bootstrap theme. I have cleared cache several times, but the ID never changes.

function bootstrap_mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['block_html_id'] == "block-views-block-homeblocks-block-1") {
    $variables['block_html_id'] = "about";
  }
}

Comment: Are you sure that this `bootstrap_mytheme_preprocess_block` function is called? What do you see if you dump the `$variables` before the condition?